# How to change individual cart quantity in React?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks

I'm building a basic shopping cart example which has 2 buttons, addtoCart that calculates total amount and Quantity which will update the qty. But when I click on it, quantities of all products are updated at once. How can I do it for specific product?

```
import React,{useContext, useState, useReducer, useEffect} from 'react'

const Wishlist=()=>{

  const product=[
    { name: "Apple", price: 10 },
    { name: "Banana", price: 20 },
    { name: "Cherry", price: 30 }
  ]

  const [total,setTotal]=useState(0)
  const [qty,setQty]=useState(1)

  const handleClick = e => {
    setTotal(prevState=>prevState+e)
  };

  const handleQty=e=>{
    setQty(prevState=>prevState+1)

  }
    return(
        <div>
      {product.map((p)=>
      <li key={p.name}>{p.name}{p.price}
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(p.price)}>Add to cart</button>
      <button onClick={()=>handleQty(p)}>x{qty}</button>

      </li>)
      }
      Price: {total}
      
        </div>
    )
}

export default Wishlist
```

Is there a way where multiple clicks on Add to Cart button updates individual quantity as well and calculates total amount? I can't seem to figure out.

[EDIT]
Now I've added a unit property as well, still all quantities are updated at once. Here's the code:

```
import React,{useContext, useState, useReducer, useEffect} from 'react'

const Wishlist=()=>{

  const product=[
    { name: "Apple", price: 10,unit:1},
    { name: "Banana", price: 20,unit:1 },
    { name: "Cherry", price: 30,unit:1 }
  ]

  const [total,setTotal]=useState(0)
  const [qty,setQty]=useState(1)

  const handleClick=e=>{
    setTotal(prevState=>prevState+e.price),
    setQty(e.unit+1)
    console.log(e)
  };

    return(
        <div>
      {product.map((p)=>
      <li key={p.name}>{p.name}{p.price}
      <button onClick={()=>handleClick(p)}>Add to cart </button>
      &nbsp;{qty}

      </li>)
      }
      Price: {total}
      
        </div>
    )
}

export default Wishlist
```

Comment: It looks like you only have a single quantity counter for all products? Or which product does `qty` represent?

Comment: @Felix Kling - A single counter, but it did change the Price. Shouldn't it do the same for quantity?

Comment: Now I have added a unit property as well, but problem is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `total` is fine, but your `quantity` is not - you can't expect it to represent your individual quantities by one number. You can store them either in `products` object (see below) or make it an array (a worse approach I think).

```
handleClick = (p) => {
    setTotal(prevState=>prevState+p.price);
    let product = products.find((pr) => pr.name === p.name);
    product.unit += 1;
    const updatedProducts = products.map(p => {
        if (product.name === p.name) return product;

        return p;
    });

    setProducts(updatedProducts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. I couldn't think of products.find((pr) => pr.name === p.name) logic, and struggled to associate each product with it's quantity. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the products in state with their quantity and update it accordingly on click.

```
const [products, setProducts]= useState([
    { name: "Apple", price: 10, quantity:0 },
    { name: "Banana", price: 20, quantity:0 },
    { name: "Cherry", price: 30, quantity:0 }
  ]);
const [total,setTotal]=useState(0);

const handleClick = (product = {}) => {
    // update quantity
    const newProducts = [
        ...products,
        {...product,
        quantity: product.quantity+1}
    ];
    // update total
    setTotal(total+product.price)
}

return (
    <div>
        {products.map((p) => (
             <li key={p.name}>{p.name}{p.price}
             <button onClick={()=>handleClick(p)}>Add to cart</button>
             <button onClick={()=>handleQty(p)}>x{p.quantity}</button>
             </li>
        ))}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks @waelvilla i tried this but the quantity doesn't change, I even tweaked a bit and put a console.log, still quantity is 0.